# Collecting externally posted form data in Angular 5

Tags: angular5, angular-routing, angular-forms

hope you can help.

I'm integrating a third party login system into the works website, but I'm having a small problem in accepting POST submissions from the third party code once a user logs in.

There's a callback (POSTback) url that once the user has successfully logged in, the user's details are sent via POST to a url of our Angular app, but I get the following message when it tries to do that:

> Cannot POST / testCollectionComponent

My question is, How do I allow the third party system to post this data to our app? Do I have to set something up in the 'testCollectionComponent' to allow external form POST submissions to the page, or is it the routing that's causing the problems? My routing (cut down for brevity) is very basic, such as this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'collect', component: testCollectionComponent}
]
```

This has sent me mental yesterday and today, so thank you for your ideas in advance :)

Comment: Is this like a jsonp callback?

Comment: could you share the log from network tab of the broser? Do you have any backend for your website? which protocol are you using for authenticatin?

Answer (score 0):

From your provided error it looks like you are Posting to the url: /testCollectionCOmponent when you should be Posting to the url: /collect. Where ever you are calling your POST you need to not send it to the component but the set route you have set in this case 'collect'.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when I was obfuscating the code! It should have read: 

Cannot POST /collect

From what I've read, I'm starting to think this may be impossible and I may have to look at another way...

Comment: Have you looked into using Oauth if you are trying to use a login service?

Comment: Frequently in the last few days, but it's not my decision, we're using a paid for service for scale.

Comment: Have you tried posting to any other test routes? Can you also post the exception that is being thrown?